# Why the page is longer on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Check this page www.danielmalek.bugs3.com/oferta.html, on Chrome you can see its a bit too long so the beam on the left side is not reaching end of site.
On firefox and IE it is seems to be right, also at localhost Chrome displays well.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">

<head>

  <title>Strony internetowe - Daniel Małek</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (){
/*$("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");*/
        /*("#slider").css("overflow", "hidden");*/
    function tytul() {
}   

        $(".galeria").click(
        function()
        {
            $("#ukryte").toggle(200);
        });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="header2"></div>
        <div id="pasek"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="przedluzenie"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu2">
            <a class="start" href="index.html"></a>
            <a class="galeria" href="#"></a>
                <div id="ukryte" style="display: none;">
                <a class="webdesign"  href="webdesign.html"></a>
                <a class="grafika"  href="grafika.html"></a>
                </div>
            <div id="oferta_b"></div>
            <a class="omnie" href="omnie.html"></a>
            <a class="kontakt" href="kontakt.html"></a>
        </div>
        </div>

    <div id="prawa_strona">
<div id="omnietxt" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
<ul style="margin-left:20px;" class="ofertatxt">
<li>Administracja istniejącymi stronami internetowymi</li>
<li>Hosting, domeny i instalacja stron na serwerze</li>
<li>Projektowanie i kodowanie stron www</li>
<li>Identyfikacja wizualna (tworzenie logo)</li>
<li>Dedykowane systemy CMS</li>
<li>Blogi Wordpress</li>
<li>Oprogramowanie sklepów KQSStore</li>
</ul>
</br>
<p class="ofertatxt">
Ponadto, wraz ze znajomymi programistami tworzymy młody, ambitny zespół, który jest w stanie stworzyć w pełni funkcjonalne i rozbudowane serwisy internetowe.</br></br>
Nie wystawiam faktury VAT, preferowany rodzaj współpracy to umowa o zlecenie lub umowa o dzieło.</p>
</div>
    <div id="footerx">
        <img src="img/foot_linia.png"></img><br>
         <p class="stopka">Copyright © 2013 Daniel Małek </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var scrollSpeed = 70;
    var step = 1;
    var current = 0;
    var imageWidth = 410;
    var headerWidth = 410;      

    var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

    function scrollBg(){
        current -= step;
        if (current == restartPosition){
            current = 0;
        }

        $('#header').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
    }

    var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function(){
var content = $('#content').height();
var winh = $(window).height();
if(content>=winh){$('#menu').height(content);}
else{
    winh=winh-200;
    $('#menu').height(winh);}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
    * {  padding: 0;  margin: 0;}
.clear {clear: both;}
html{}
html, body, #container, #content{}
body {background: url('img/tekstura.png');background-repeat:repeat-y repeat-x;background-color:#d5d5d5;}
#container {margin: 0 auto;  position:relative;}

#content {margin: 0 auto;position:relative;width:960px;overflow:auto;}

#header {background-color:#2099c8;background: url('img/heder/tekstura.png') repeat-x;  height:160px;  margin:0 auto;  position:relative;  width:100%;box-shadow: 0 0 30px 9px white;}

#pasek{height:3px;background: url('img/heder/pasek.png') repeat-x;}

#header2{background: url('img/heder/przod2.png') no-repeat;background-repeat:repeat-y repeat-x;margin: 0 auto;width:960px;  height:157px;}

#gradient_poziom{height:37px; background: url('img/gradient_poziom.png') repeat-x;}

#prawa_strona{ float:right;width:720px; margin-right:10px;}

#przedluzenie{width:209px; height:40px;background-color:black;margin:0 auto;position:relative;right:376px;background: url('img/gradient_pion.png') repeat-y;}
#menu {float:left;width:209px;margin-right:5px;background: url('img/gradient_pion.png') repeat-y;}
#menu2{float:right;margin-right:20px;}

#ukryte {position:relative;left:23px;}

#start_b {background: url('img/start_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
.start {background:url('img/start.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;width:169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.start:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

#galeria_b {background: url('img/galeria_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.galeria {background: url('img/galeria.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;overflow:hidden;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.galeria:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

#webdesign_b {background: url('img/webdesign_b.png') no-repeat;height:20px;width: 142px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.webdesign {background: url('img/webdesign.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:20px;overflow:hidden;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.webdesign:hover {background-position: 0px -20px;}

#grafika_b {background: url('img/grafika_b.png') no-repeat;height:20px;width: 142px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.grafika {background: url('img/grafika.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:20px;overflow:hidden;width: 169px;margin-bottom:25px;}
a.grafika:hover {background-position: 0px -20px;}

#oferta{background: url('img/oferta_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 142px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.oferta {background: url('img/oferta.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;width: 142px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.oferta:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

#omnie_b{background: url('img/omnie_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.omnie {background: url('img/omnie.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.omnie:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

#oferta_b{background: url('img/oferta_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.oferta {background: url('img/oferta.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.oferta:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

#kontakt_b {background: url('img/kontakt_b.png') no-repeat;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.kontakt {background: url('img/kontakt.png') no-repeat;display:block;height:29px;width: 169px;margin-bottom:15px;}
a.kontakt:hover {background-position: 0px -29px;}

.minwebd{border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;float:left;position:relative;left:10px;}

.cien{display:block;height:28px;width:216px;float:left;margin-left:22px;}
#cienie{z-index:-1;float:right;position:relative;top:-8px;}

#jrs{margin-top:25px;float:right;margin-left:7px;}
.jrs{background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);width:218px;float:left;}
.jrs_img{}
.jrs_tekst{margin: 0 10px 15px 10px; text-align:justify;color:#464646;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
.znak_plus{position:relative;float:left;width:20px;font-size:20px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin-top:15px;text-align:center;color:#3f3f3f;}


#footerx{float:right;margin:20px 0;width:412px;}
.stopka{float:right;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:0.6em;color:#2e2e2e;position:relative;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px;}

.obrazek1{
height:159px;
width: 198px;
float:left;
border: 1px solid #417f99;
}

.obrazek2{}

#galgraf{margin-right:30px;float:left;}
#napis{ width:190px;float:right;height:35px;background: white;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); display: block; padding: 5px ;  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;}
#wstep{float:left; position:relative; width:auto;  background: white; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);margin: 0 0 30px 66px; padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;color:#464646;}

#gallery{
float:right;
}

#gallery2{
float:left;
width:200px;
}

#webdopisy{
float:left;
}

#webdopis{float:right;width: 430px; background: white;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); display: block;margin: 0 0 15px 40px; padding:15px;color:#464646;}
#beczka{margin-bottom:30px;position:relative;float:left;}
.webdopis {}

.opis a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#006c96;
}

.opis a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
color:#006c96;
}
h1 {
color:black;
font-size:0.9em;
font-family:tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-weight:100;
text-align:center;
}

.omnietxt{line-height:20px;color:#464646;font-size:0.9em;float:left;font-family:arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding: 0 5px 0 5px;}

.ofertatxt{line-height:20px;color:#464646;font-size:0.9em;font-family:arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:justify}

#omnietxt{
  float:left;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); 
  display: block;
  padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0 0 110px 120px;
}

#wysokosc{
height:420px;
}

/* LAJTBOKS */

.thumb {
float:left;
margin: 0 0 0 20px ;
border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
 } 

 .clearFloat {
  clear:both;
 } 

/* KONTAKT */

#numery{  padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;float:left;position:relative;left:265px;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);   margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:150px;}

.gg1 {position:relative;top:2px;left: 13px;}

.gg2 {font-style:italic;font-size:1.2em;position:relative;top:5px;left:15px;}
.adres1 {color:#015d81;font-size:15;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.adres2 {position:relative;top:5px;color:#015d81;font-size:15;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Can you add the code in question here and perhaps a screenshot image. This is so the question will still be relevant as you make changes to your site in the future.

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: where is the notice of the free-hoster in Chrome 27?

Comment: I don't think that depends of hoster, just checked id on another one and it's still bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two scripts embedded into HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function(){
    var content = $('#content').height();
    var winh = $(window).height();
    if(content>=winh){$('#menu').height(content);}
    else{
      winh=winh-200;
      $('#menu').height(winh);}
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function(){
    var content = $('#content').height();
    $('#menu').height(content);
  });
</script>
```

Both fire at the same time: `$(window).load`, and both do the same thing: `$('#menu').height(value);`, but the value is different.

Obviously, this is erroneous. Probably in Chrome those snippets finish in different order than in other browsers, thus the difference.

#### UPD #1

I'm opening your link now with Chrome, and the vertical scrollbar does not appear. I assume my solution worked, please don't forget to accept the question. ;)

But do you know that you don't need Javascript to solve this task?

Here's an example how vertical stretching can be done in pure CSS: [CSS 3 col template 100% same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693817/css-3-col-template-100-same-height/15699812#15699812)

Also, you should not use non-semantic elements for decoration: `#przedluzenie`, `#pasek` etc. That can be also solved in pure CSS without messing your HTML.

Comment: fixed it, still the same

Comment: Updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: i have got still the scrollbar displayed... Now trying to solve it with css3 only maybe it will help. What do you mean by 'accept the question'?

Comment: This is how your page looks to me in Chrome after you modified it: http://i.imgur.com/xDXHdEX.jpg No scrollbar. I consider your problem to be solved. If you agree, click the tick icon at the top-left of my answer.

Comment: I just told my friend to turn on the page and and his computer it looks good too, so it seems that there is something with my software :) Thanks for the help :)